# Add item to different div from PHP generated List (w/jQuery + AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have little experience with AJAX and jQuery so apologize if this seems trivial.

I have a list of ingredients that are generated from a DB via PHP `foreach` loop:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5 pure-u-lg-2-5 content-left">
            <div id="scroll" class="card">
              <a href="javascript:showhide('green')"><h2 class="is-center">green</h2></a>
              <ul id="greens" class="card-content-ingredients" style="list-style-type: none;">
                <?php
                foreach ($greens as $green) {
                  echo "<li>";
                  echo "<span class='item-name-small'>" . $green['name'] . "</span>";
                  echo "<span class='item-description-menu'>" . $green['description'] . "</span>";
                  echo "<span class='content-right'>";
                  echo "<a class='minus increment' href='#'> - </a>";
                  echo "<input class='quantity' type='text' size='1' id='" . $green['id'] . "' name='" . $green['id'] . "' value='0'>";
                  echo "<a class='plus increment' href='#'> + </a>";
                  echo "</span>";
                  echo "</li>";
                  echo "</br>";
                }?>
              </ul>

              <a href="javascript:showhide('essentials')"><h2 class="is-center">essentials</h2></a>
              <ul id="essentials" class="card-content-ingredients" style="list-style-type: none;">
                <?php
                foreach ($essentials as $essential) {
                  if (($essential['subtype'] == "veggies") || ($essential['subtype'] == "fruit")) {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo "<span class='item-name-small'>" . $essential['name'] . " </span>";
                    echo "<span class='item-description-menu'> " . $essential['description'] . "</span>";
                    echo "<span class='content-right'>";
                    echo "<a class='minus increment' href='#'> - </a>";
                    echo "<input class='quantity' type='text' size='1' id='" . $essential['id'] . "' name='" . $essential['id'] . "' value='0'>";
                    echo "<a class='plus increment' href='#'> + </a>";
                    echo "</span>";
                    echo "</li>";
                    echo "</br>";
                  }
                }?>
              </ul>

              <a href="javascript:showhide('crunch')"><h2 class="is-center">crunch</h2></a>
              <ul id="crunch" class="card-content-ingredients" style="list-style-type: none;">
                <?php
                foreach ($essentials as $essential) {
                  if (($essential['subtype'] == "crunch")) {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo "<span class='item-name-small'>" . $essential['name'] . " </span>";
                    echo "<span class='item-description-menu'> " . $essential['description'] . "</span>";
                    echo "<span class='content-right'>";
                    echo "<a class='minus increment' href='#'> - </a>";
                    echo "<input class='quantity' type='text' size='1' id='" . $essential['id'] . "' name='" . $essential['id'] . "' value='0'>";
                    echo "<a class='plus increment' href='#'> + </a>";
                    echo "</span>";
                    echo "</li>";
                    echo "</br>";
                  }
                }?>
              </ul>

              <a href="javascript:showhide('grains')"><h2 class="is-center">grains</h2></a>
              <ul id="grains" class="card-content-ingredients" style="list-style-type: none;">
                <?php
                foreach ($essentials as $essential) {
                  if (($essential['subtype'] == "grains")) {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo "<span class='item-name-small'>" . $essential['name'] . " </span>";
                    echo "<span class='item-description-menu'> " . $essential['description'] . "</span>";
                    echo "<span class='content-right'>";
                    echo "<a class='minus increment' href='#'> - </a>";
                    echo "<input class='quantity' type='text' size='1' id='" . $essential['id'] . "' name='" . $essential['id'] . "' value='0'>";
                    echo "<a class='plus increment' href='#'> + </a>";
                    echo "</span>";
                    echo "</li>";
                    echo "</br>";
                  }
                }?>
              </ul>
            </div> <!-- END CARD -->
          </div> <!-- END ESSENTIALS -->
```

Currently, I have it that next to each ingredient, a `-` and `+` appear next to a text input. What I'm trying to do is change the code that when a customer clicks on each individual item, it is added to a different div that has a summary of their order. The second div is on the same page as the item list.

Comment: What is your problem, then? Did you tried anything? Where's your JS code?

Comment: You don't require Ajax to move data from one element towards another. Just use the unique id from the clicked item as a selector, get the current content from the div with `var divContent = $("div").html();` and add the content of the clicked item towards it. After just set the divs innerHTML again and done. Unless extra data is pulled from the database when moving the data.

Comment: @AlanMachado - honestly, I didn't even know where to start. I keep trying different tutorials but i'm not clearly understanding what's going on. Was just looking for a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to copy the list item to a different div you can do it like this:

```
$(function (){
    $('ul.card-content-ingredients li').click(function(){
        $('#new-div-id ul').append($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. So this appends the list and I would use AJAX if I needed to process information or parameters? (i.e. when adding item, add the calorie information.

Comment: This only copies the html list-item from the original unordered list to another.  If you're wanting to add additional information about the content of that list item I would recommend using a data attribute in your list-item containing the items ID. - <li data-item-id="1234">...</li> - Then in the click function above get the id with var id=$(this).attr("data-item-id"); Then use ajax to get the additional information about that item using the ID.